# Cassandra Triggers Buggy Code

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, cassandra-cli, cqlsh

How do I debug a code that has errors in Cassandra Triggers ?

Here is the code which may have errors:

This code sends the updates to another application SampleConsumer()

```
public Collection<Mutation> augment(ByteBuffer key, ColumnFamily update) {

    LinkedList<Mutation> dummyReturn = new LinkedList<Mutation>();
    SampleConsumer cons = new SampleConsumer();

    String payload = "key="+key.toString()+"&";

    // get the column names and their values in a string
    for (CellName columnName : update.getColumnNames()) {
        payload += (columnName.toString()+"="+update.getColumn(columnName).value().toString()+"&");
    }

    // This publishing to the consumer works perfectly if i hardcode a payload instead of calculating it.
    cons.write(payload);

    return dummyReturn;
}
```

I get this error while updating a column family using cqlsh

```
[cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.7.31 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]
cqlsh> create TABLE store.users(user_name varchar PRIMARY KEY, password varchar);
cqlsh> CREATE TRIGGER ctrigger ON store.users USING 'com.castrigger.casNotify';
cqlsh> INSERT INTO store.users (user_name, password) VALUES ('sampleuser','samplepass');
**TSocket read 0 bytes**
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see cassandra's log. By default, it's located at

> /var/log/cassandra/system.log

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to debug Triggers in Cassandra.
As:

1. Using Cassandra system log
2. Staring a single node Cassandra, which is a java application in Debug mode with

`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n`

then connect from remote debugger[say eclipse, where you may have the coede for your  trigger].